# How to skip a test method if another previous test method failed with unittest in Python?

Tags: python-unittest, python-decorators

I have one unittest test case with two different methods. I'd like that my second method to be skipped, if the first one fails.

I am using the decorator @unittest.skipIf but I cannot find the proper condition for it.

```py
class myTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,2)

    @unittest.skipIf(????,'test_2 was skipped because test_1 failed')
    def test_2(self):
        pass

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skipIf` is evaluated at class declaration time, which is too early to know the result of `test_1`. Unit tests are meant to be independent, and you're implying that these tests aren't independent, so one option would be to put the test 2 logic within test 1; it won't execute if the earlier part of the test fails:

```
class myTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,2)
        # move test 2 logic here
        self.assertTrue(something)
```

Alternatively, relying on the fact that tests are sorted alphabetically, you could use the `failfast` option, which will cause the test runner to stop as soon as the first test fails. Obviously this approach will also skip any subsequent tests after `test_2` as well.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried these both approaches but I was hoping, there was some other more elegant solution using skipIf.